# Running Apache as a different user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server, user-accounts

When I run the `ps -efH` command to list out all the process, I can see Apache running as `root` and seems to have sub-processes running as `www-data`. Here's the excerpt:

```
root     30117     1  0 09:10 ?        00:00:00   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 30119 30117  0 09:10 ?        00:00:00     /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 30120 30117  0 09:10 ?        00:00:00     /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 30121 30117  0 09:10 ?        00:00:00     /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Can I make Apache and all sub-processes run as different user `apache2d:apache2d`? If so how? I read somewhere that the settings for this can be found in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` but that file seems to be empty? Can this be accomplished by changing the owner and group of the `/etc/init.d/apache2` script and then settings the setuid flag on it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Apache has to run as root initially in order to bind to port 80. If you don't run it as root initially then you cannot bind to port 80. If you want to bind to some port above 1024 then yes, you can. Otherwise don't worry about root. That is the parent Apache process and does not serve any requests. It will spawn child processes and drop privileges for handling requests.

To change the Apache user set the `User` and `Group` parameters in your Apache config.

Comment: Well, sorry to digress, but I notice that haproxy can run as haproxy(not as root), and bind tcp 80 port. How does this achieve? Any enlightenment?

Comment: It doesn't. Processes can only bind to ports under 1024 if it has super user privilege. So haproxy is either starting as root and dropping privileges (probably) or setuid root (unlikely).

Comment: You don't need to run it as root, you just need to allow your 'apache' user access to restricted ports (ie, those below 1024).  This answer explains how you can use 'authbind' to do that: https://superuser.com/questions/710253/allow-non-root-process-to-bind-to-port-80-and-443

Comment: Running the parent apache process as non-priviledged user is perfectly possible. `setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /usr/sbin/apache2` allows it to bind non-privileged ports.

Answer (score 6):

@bahamat explains it pretty well, but I'll add a little more detail.

In the course of normal operation, the root-owned apache process will not perform any actual operations other than listening on port 80 and forwarding incoming connections to its (safely non-privileged, as the `www-data` user) children.

The location of the master configuration file depends on compile-time options and varies per distribution, but `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` is a good starting guess.

Also, if you're setting up a multi-user webhosting system, you might want to look into [SuExec and fcgid](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-apache2-with-mod_fcgid-and-php5-on-ubuntu-8.10) so that each individual webhosting user's apache process runs as said user -- so that if one user is negligent with their security, other users won't be affected.

Answer (score 6):

In Ubuntu at least, the settings for this are in `/etc/apache2/envvars`. Tweak those, then restart apache and you're off and running.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me!  I'm setting up a ubuntu vagrant box, and for some reason /etc/apache2/httpd.conf wasn't being used to load the user and group.  envars seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Also, check out [Apache2 ITK MPM](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/).

It forks an Apache thread with the assigned `uid`/`gid`, this let's you keep using `mod_php`. No more `chmod`/`chown` etc.

Comment: Upvoting for `mpm_itk` which is a significant improvement over suexec/fcgid

Answer (score 0):

**Mac OSX:**

What worked for me is going into apache config file:

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

In this file i've searched for **User** or **Group**

and bumped into:

```
User _www
Group _www
```

I've changed it to what ever user / group I needed (in my case to the user / group who is the owner of my web app files which you can see. And this you can check by using the simple 'ls -l' command)